# 'as' vs `=` in select into statement

Tags: sql-server

Is there any difference between those syntaxes? Any performance or other impacts if we use one instead of the other?

**Syntax 1**

```
select MyField = 'something'
  into aTable
  from anotherTable
```

**Syntax 2**

```
select 'something' as MyField
  into aTable
  from anotherTable
```

My question is for [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server), however if others (e.g. MySQL, Postgres) handle such cases differently feel free to mention it.

Note: I am not asking which 'way' is the best to use. I am asking if there is any documented difference, or if anyone experienced any difference. So I do not consider this question opinion-based.

Comment: There shouldn't be a difference.

Comment: There's no difference. *Personally*, I prefer the `AS` form, but [others disagree](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases) (Also, insert standard rant that the best way to write good code is to write clean, readable code and set performance goals. Then measure. Only if it's not meeting your goals should you start thinking about "performance", and you should do that in a targetted fashion, not by learning "always best" rules)

Comment: No difference whatsoever. It's only a matter of readability. Choose one and stick with it.

Comment: Thank you all! @Damien_The_Unbeliever nice resource, I was looking something like this to read.

Comment: The second version would port to most other RDBMS, whereas the first might not.  Something to consider in terms of flexibility of your code.

Comment: In postgres 9.6 you can just do select ‘something’ MyField into aTable from anotherTable but I don‘t know why an alias is necessary